# If text contains characters other than

Tags: c#, string

I am in the process of writing a StyleCop rule. As a part of this I am searching for strings.

If they contain any text other than `'/', '{', '}'` and `whitespace` characters, I want to do something with them.

How can I target only the strings that contain anything other than these characters?

Mind you: they can also contain the above said characters; but if any other than these gets discovered I want them to be flagged.

Edit: As requested, my progess on the rule so far. I am checking comments to see if they contain disabled code. Because this flags many lines of code with simply: `//    {` (and others); I want such lines to be excluded.

```
public static void IsCommentDisabledCodeComment(Class classItem, IfSQRules context)
{
    foreach (CsToken token in classItem.Tokens)
    {
        if (token.CsTokenType == CsTokenType.MultiLineComment || token.CsTokenType == CsTokenType.SingleLineComment)
        {
            if (token.Text != "//   }" && token.Text != "//  }" && token.Text != "// }" && token.Text != "//}" && token.Text != "//    }" && token.Text != "////     }" && token.Text != "//      }" && token.Text != "//       }" && token.Text != "////   {" && token.Text != "//  {" && token.Text != "// {" && token.Text != "//    {" && token.Text != "//     {" && token.Text != "//      {" && token.Text != "//       {" && token.Text != "//{")
            {
                if (token.Text.Contains("()") || token.Text.Contains("[]") || token.Text.Contains("{") || token.Text.Contains("}"))
                    context.AddViolation(classItem, token.LineNumber, "ThereShouldNotBeAnyDisabledCode", token.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you see here is a really, really bad approach at achieving this, but this is obviously not something I want to use.

Comment: What have you tried? Depending on your performance requirements, a simple regex should work fine. Or just loop...

Comment: To be honest I have not been able to find any approach to achieve what I am looking for; hence my question.

Comment: So you want to check, if the string _doesn't_ contain a `/` or `{` or `}`?

Comment: Well, how far are you in the writing of your StyleCop rule? What does it currently look like?

Comment: I'm guessing a regex something like `"^[^/{}]*$` should work.

Comment: Max Mommersteeg: That is correct. Jean Hominal: I have added code on how far I am.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow: Could you explain the working of said regex?

Comment: The first '^' means the the start of the string; the final '$' means the end of the string; the '[^/{}]' means not the characters '/', '{' or '}' and; the '*' means 0 or more. So it reads as match strings where every character between the start and the end of the string is not one of '/', '{' or '}', which is what you want to assert.

Comment: @Matthijs "^" = start of string, "[" = start of group, "^" = group negation; "/{}" = group members, "]" = end of group, "*" = any number of incidents of previous item (the group), "$" = end of string

Comment: Reading your post I don't think that what you asked for gives the behaviour that you are after!

Comment: And what about the whitespace character I am also trying to detect, how can I include that in a regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the following:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(token.Text, @"^[/{}\s]*$"))
{
  // your code
}
```

Alternative:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(token.Text, @"[^/{}\s]"))
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if there are other characters than those three you can use the efficient `Enumerable.Except` + `Enumerable.Any`:

```
static char[] comments = { '/', '{', '}', ' ', '\t' };

public static void IsCommentDisabledCodeComment(Class classItem, IfSQRules context)
{
    // ...
        if (token.Text.Except(comments).Any())
        {
            // something other 
        }
    // ...
}
```

However, that's a very naive approach which just answers your initial question. It does not take care about the order of the characters. It does also not treat tab- or new-line characters as white-space (as [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)). If that's not sufficient you need a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23240592/284240) or loop.

**Edit**: Instead of LINQ you can also use the efficient [`String.IndexOfAny`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
if (token.Text.IndexOfAny(comments) >= 0)
{
    // something other 
}
```

Comment: What about the whitespace characters? Can I add that in the commentsarray? Also, you say this is a very naive approach; what would be a better approach?

Comment: And performancewise? Can I better use this or a regular expression?

Comment: @Matthijs: this will be more efficient but the question is if that matters at all or if it's more important to get better results. `Except` uses a set which needs some memory but is more efficient than a loop or regex, `Any` stops as soon as a different character was found.

Comment: It does matter because it will be run on very big projects containing many lines of code; I need it to perform relatively quick :)

Comment: Also the array you've presented does not seem to compile!

Comment: @Matthijs: if you have a working regex use that until the performance is really a problem.

Comment: Your code actually gave some false-positives, why I am not sure. The regex performed correctly, plus because of its faster performance; I am using that. Thanks for the solution though, it did teach me something! :)

Comment: @Matthijs: i'm sure that the performance is the only thing that is better with this approach and the false positive might be caused by other [white-space characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) like tab or newline as mentioned in my answer. But use the regex if it's working until you need a more efficient (but possibly less strict) way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You can use [string.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of LINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: They turned out to be tabs instead of whitespace characters, makes sense indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthijs: you could include it `'\t'`.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov:   `IndexOfAny` is another efficient (less memory expensive) approach, good point. Edited my answer to include that option.